# Не скрывать header при малом кол-ве элементов в списке

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Есть метод в котором в зависимости от прокрутки появляется или исчезает header.
Но так как мой список периодически меняется(изменяется кол-во) то при наличии 2-3 элементов в списке я не хочу чтобы header исчезал, но увы чёт не получается дореализовать. Может кто подскажет чего дельного?
Метод:

```
 public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            firstVisiblePosition = recyclerLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
            if (lastScrollState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING
                    && scrollDirection == ScrollDirection.SCROLL_DOWN) {
                hideHeader();
            } else if (lastScrollState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING
                    && scrollDirection == ScrollDirection.SCROLL_UP
                    && firstVisiblePosition < 10) {
                showHeader();
            }
            lastScrollState = newState;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал Вам изначально определиться с Вашим `recyclerView`. 
Если я правильно понял, от кол-ва элементов в recyclerView вы отображаете или скрываете `header`.

Соответственно изначально попробуйте высчитать в Вашем методе `hideHeader` следующие значения: высоту элемента списка, высоту вьюшки ну и кол-во элементов в списке.

В зависимости от данных параметров уже можете играться с условиями и отображать нужные Вам элементы.

Получить следующие значения можно примерно следующим образом:

```
 int itemHeight =  recyclerView.getChildAt(0).getMeasuredHeight();
 int fragmentHeight = getView().getMeasuredHeight();
 int count = adapter.getItemCount();
```

Ну и само условие исходя из полученных значений будет примерно следующим для hideHeader:

```
fragmentHeight > count * itemHeight
```

**UPD:**

Для того чтобы не выбивало, попробуйте дополнительно добавить следующее условие в Ваш if и else:

```
&& adapter != null
```

И я так полагаю у Вас в проекте не скрывается сразу header т.к. firstVisiblePosition это по логике обозначение первого элемента. Попробуйте что то вроде:

```
adapter.getItemCount() > 10
```

Ну а вообще т.к. скоерй всего Вы ваше приложение будете использовать и на планшетах, то посоветовал бы посчитать сколько всего элементов располагается у Вас на экране самого широко разрешения планшета элементов и установил бы эту цифру, так как думаю что header возможно будет прыгать.

Comment: Попрежнему выбивает,  но отловить ошибку не получается. Раз на раз + header скрывается не сразу, только при каком-то кол-ве пролистывания.